# Persistent UILocalNotification on Lock Screen

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I've noticed that the built-in iOS Reminders app lets notifications stay on the lock screen until the reminder is marked as complete in the app. Is it possible to replicate this same behavior (persistent local notifications)

Comment: Yes, I have a few third-party apps that have the same feature.

Comment: @fbara what do you mean?

Comment: You asked if it was possible to replicate that behavior. I answered that yes it is possible because other apps do it.

Comment: @fbara how do I do this?